# List elements in a list instead of strings?

Tags: python

I have a list of word tokens, such as:

```
my_list = [[('abc, 123'), ('def, 456')], [('ghi, 789'), ('abc, 456')]]
```

and I want to do some preprocessing with regular expressions such as replacing **", "** with a **whitespace** (eg. string = re.sub(r"(, )", " ", string). Afterwards, I want to append the strings again to another list. All in all, I want to get a preprocessed list which looks like that:

```
my_list_preprocessed = [[('abc 123'), ('def 456')], [('ghi 789'), ('abc 456')]]
```

Currently I tried to implement it like that:

```
my_list_preprocessed = []
for string in my_list:
  string = re.sub(r"(, )", " ", str(string))
  my_list_preprocessed.append(string)
```

However, instead of getting the intended result. I am receiving a list of strings:

```
my_list = ["['abc 123', 'def 456']", "['ghi 789', 'abc 456']"]
```

What can I improve to get my intended result?

Comment: Well, you are overkilling with regex. If you just want to replace ", " with " " then do `mystring = mystring.replace(", ", " ")`

Comment: If I understand correctly, your list is a list of a list of string items. If you want to iterate over the innermost string, you need to do a nested loop. The outermost loop iterates over each inner list and the innermost loop iterates over each string in that list.

The inner `(` and `)` brackets aren't really necessary by the way, unless you want to make the items a tuple, in which case you also need to add a trailing comma.

Comment: too many typo errors in your code... are you sure you are trying with `[('abc, 123'), ('def, 456')]` ? and not `[('abc', '123'), ('def', '456')]`.. your current `my_list` which you are showing is tuple has one and only element.. I don't think it matters if what you have written is correct.

Comment: @StefanPochmann at he stored all the string withing brackets.... what you call `('abc, 123')`.. string within bracket.. i see it tuple with single element.. either it is `('abc', '123')` or `'(abc, 123)'`. but seeing typo mistakes in question I'm not sure which one user prefer...

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you want to remove the comma separating the alphabets from the numerals. One thing you should note though is that your parentheses are redundant as what you have is a string and not a tuple. Here are some suggested corrections that I think will help you achieve what you want.

```
my_list = [[('abc, 123'), ('def, 456')], [('ghi, 789'), ('abc, 456')]]

my_list_preprocessed = []
for item in my_list:
    item_preprocessed = []
    for inner_item in item:
        inner_item = inner_item.replace(",", "")
        item_preprocessed.append(inner_item)
    my_list_preprocessed.append(item_preprocessed)
print(my_list_preprocessed)
```

Comment: Your code gives `['abc 123', 'def 456', 'ghi 789', 'abc 456']`. The output should be `[['abc 123', 'def 456'], ['ghi 789', 'abc 456']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get what you desire:

```
my_list = [[('abc, 123'), ('def, 456')], [('ghi, 789'), ('abc, 456')]]

my_list_preprocessed = [[x[0].replace(',', ''), x[1].replace(',','')] for x in my_list]
```

However, notice that the output of this operation is:

```
[['abc 123', 'def 456'], ['ghi 789', 'abc 456']]
```

and not

```
[[('abc 123'), ('def 456')], [('ghi 789'), ('abc 456')]]
```

That's because a tuple can't consist of one item. If you really want tuples, you should use this code:

```
my_list_preprocessed = [[(x[0].replace(',', ''),), (x[1].replace(',',''),)] for x in my_list]
```

Notice the added commas. These are used to create tuples that contain only one item.

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
my_list = [[('abc, 123'), ('def, 456')], [('ghi, 789'), ('abc, 456')]]
```

**Code:**

```
import re
my_list_preprocessed = map(lambda x:map(lambda y:re.sub(r',',' ',y),x),my_list)
```

**output:**

```
[['abc  123', 'def  456'], ['ghi  789', 'abc  456']]
```